# Visual Studio localhost redirects to 10.7.192.8

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, localhost

Running Visual Studio 2013, when the chrome opens it tries to resolve

```
http://localhost:58893/
```

but after like 2 seconds it redirects to

```
http://10.7.192.8/
```

and that ip which I don't know where it is coming from, can't be opened or anything so I can't debug my website and it's driving me crazy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you do `ipconfig` from a console window is the ip of your computer 10.7.192.8?

Comment: Are you trying to run a web application from Visual Studio? What does your main page contain?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No my ip is 192.168.0.1

Comment: Is there any chance its in your web config? is this a project someone else gave you to look at or one you created?

Comment: @RonBeyer it is a web application which was working fine 2 days ago while debugging. I've installed some application(webmethods) which I assume messed up with something... I'm not sure

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no I made the whole project and it was just working fine 2 days ago and suddenly it redirects like that...

Comment: If you added something, why not share it so we can see? How can we correct what you added if we don't know what it is?

Comment: @RonBeyer I did not add anything, I simple ran the application 2 days ago to check something and didn't make any changes to it then company installed webmethods on my system and now it's not working. could it be an iis configuration issue?

Comment: Please run Fiddler, and check is it a real redirect or you just supposing its a redirect

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party firewall installed?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: @g.pickardou no I don't and windows firewall is also turned off.

Comment: @g.pickardou I will try fiddler and will update you

Comment: @g.pickardou I've tried with fiddler and the moment chrome was trying to resolve localhost, fiddler was showing the http connection for 10.7.192.8 ... what does that mean?

Comment: Do you see any 301 302 http code in fiddler or just 200?

Comment: Please disable _all_ extensions in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Check your host file (%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) for a line that looks like:

localhost 10.7.192.8

Remove it.

Comment: no the only uncommented line in my hosts file is  127.0.0.1    localhost

Comment: and why would the port is lost if that's a simple DNS (hosts file) resolve?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense because when the Hosts file says `localhost 10.7.192.8` Chrome shouldn't even redirect or show that it's trying to got to `10.7.192.8`

Comment: With all my respect, this is not an answer, just a guess, so this usually goes to a comment, like "Could you please check your  %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file" or "please attach your "%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file"